# Android Studio 2.2.3 Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: android, firebase

I know that this questions has been asked many times here, but none of the recommendation solutions works out.

In a sudden after compiling ready to run on Emulator, my IDE give an error at the R.id attribute and R.layout. Every Java files suddenly give the same error even I don't make any changes to the file.
I have already tried :

```
File->Invalidata Caches/Restart Invalidata and Restart
Build->Make Module
Build->Make Project
Build->Clean Project
Build->Rebuild Project
```

This is my build.grade file for the app module :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sabrine.sos_remorquage"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Any errors in console? Can u post that?

Comment: Do u have proper import statements?

Comment: R- means Resource. you should check on resource file thoroughly. because, it is filing the error in your app. it may be even single dot will through an error. styles,string,raw,attr,color,layout,drawable,anim,menu or even custom xml layout files or folder

Answer (score 0):

you should use the latest version of the firebase

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
```

it might solve your problem

Comment: I fixed firebase errors but it still cannot resolve the R!

Comment: then please check your resource files there might be some error in one of your res files